# Finding the sum of Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: fibonacci

What would be the most efficient way to calculate the sum of Fibonacci numbers from `F(n)` to `F(m)` where `F(n)` and `F(m)` are nth and mth Fibonacci numbers respectively and 0 =< n <= m <10<sup>9</sup> (with F(0)=0, F(1)=1).

For example, if `n=0`, `m=3`, we need to find `F(0)+F(1)+F(2)+F(3)`.

Just by brute force it will take long time for the range of `n` and `m` mentioned. If it can be done via matrix exponentiation then how?

Comment: I would be very happy to know the application of this answer!

Comment: I think we've teased you long enough, in particular with the hint about Binet (instead you should use linear algebra as hinted in your question).  Also beware that The `F(m+2) - F(n+2) - 2` isn't quite correct but you can figure it out given that the sum of fibo # to n is effectively F(n+2) -1 (hint: you want the sum _inclusive_ of F(n) and hence you need to substract the sum of fibo # up to `n-1` and _substract_ this from F(m+2) -2).  Anyway... it looking and smelling like `HOMEWORK`, the SO community shouldn't help too much ;-)

Comment: @mjv - it smells like coding competition problem to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`F(m+2) - F(n+2) - 2` ([discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223103250/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52707.html))

Literally, the sum of your upper bound m, minus the sum of your lower bound n.

Comment: This is not completely correct. The answer is simply F(m+2) - F(n+2), since the (-1) terms cancel out.

Comment: @JørgenFogh Not that it is *not completely correct*, it is actually completely incorrect. No offence to the OP of the answer.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ The idea is correct though. The answer is consistently off by 2, not completely unrelated to the correct answer.

Comment: @JørgenFogh Yeah right. BTW, I have added an answer of my own on this post. You are welcome to take a look and make a comment ;-)

Answer (score 23):

The first two answers (oldest ones) are seemingly *incorrect* to me. According to this [discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223103250/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52707.html) which is already cited in one of the answers, sum of first `n` Fibonacci numbers is given by:

```
SumFib(n) = F[n+2] - 1                          (1)
```

Now, lets define `SumFib(m, n)` as sum of Fibonacci numbers from `m` to `n` **inclusive** (as required by OP) (see footnote). So:

```
SumFib(m, n) = SumFib(n) - SumFib(m-1)
```

Note the second term. It is so because `SumFib(m)` includes `F[m]`, but we want sum from `F[m]` to `F[n]` *inclusive*. So we subtract sum up to `F[m-1]` from sum up to `F[n]`. Simple kindergarten maths, isn't it? `:-)`

```
SumFib(m, n) = SumFib(n) - SumFib(m-1)
             = (F[n+2] - 1) - (F[m-1 + 2] - 1)    [using eq(1)]
             = F[n+2] - 1 - F[m+1] + 1
             = F[n+2] - F[m+1]

Therefore, SumFib(m, n) = F[n+2] - F[m+1]                    (2)
```

Example:

```
m = 3, n = 7
Sum = F[3] + F[4] + F[5] + F[6] + F[7]
    = 2 + 3 + 5 + 8 + 13
    = 31
```

And by using `(2)` derived above:

```
SumFib(3, 7) = F[7+2] - F[3+1]
             = F[9] - F[4]
             = 34 - 3
             = 31
```

---

Bonus:
When `m` and `n` are large, you need efficient algorithms to generate Fibonacci numbers. Here is a very good [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205347/http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/) that explains one way to do it.

---

Footnote: In the question `m` and `n` of OP satisfy this range: `0 =< n <= m`, but in my answer the range is a bit altered, it is `0 =< m <= n`.

Comment: +1. I'm very surprised at the upvotes on the two answers above yours. Should we really expect that SumFib(n,n) <= 0 as they claim if the sum is inclusive?

Comment: Thanks @Daenerys . I don't think so. `SumFib(n, n)` should very sensibly equal `Fib(n)`.

Comment: Thanks! this should be the right answer. Saved my day :)

Answer (score 13):

Given that "the sum of the first n Fibonacci numbers is the (n + 2)nd Fibonacci number minus 1." (thanks, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)), you can calculate `F(m + 2) - F(n + 2)` (shouldn't have had `-2`, see [Sнаđошƒаӽ's answer for what I'd overlooked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40930139/223391)). Use [Binet's Fibonacci number formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) to quickly calculate `F(m + 2)` and `F(n + 2)`. Seems fairly efficient to me.

Update: found an old SO post, ["nth fibonacci number in sublinear time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776685/sum-of-fibonacci-numbers), and (due to accuracy as [mjv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166686/mjv) and [Jim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153430/jim-lewis) have pointed out in the comments), [you can't really escape an `O(n)` solution to calculate `F(n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525521/nth-fibonacci-number-in-sublinear-time/1550208#1550208).

Comment: @MrGomez had to +1 you too for beating me to the basic formula :)

Comment: All good on the formula.  When it comes to computation, you'll need a mighty precise calculation of Phi and/or sqrt(5) to use Binet on big numbers...

Comment: @mjv, true - I'm not sure how precise they need to be to avoid rounding errors out to `F(1 billion)`...

Comment: @jball: F(10^9) has about 204 million digits, if I've calculated correctly, so you'll probably need to know phi and its large powers to that precision.

Comment: @Jim Lewis, seems like a traditional iteration is the way to go for the larger values then. That would be pretty slow out in the millions, though.

Comment: @jball : no need to iterate, using "square and multiply" one can compute the fibo matrix to the desired power _relatively_ inexpensively.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm via matrix property explanation found [here](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=598077&start=0&mc=4&view=flat) and [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~dan/class/161/notes/7/Fib.html)

```cs
class Program
{
    static int FibMatrix(int n, int i, int h, int j, int k)
    {
        int t = 0;

        while (n > 0)
        {
            if (n % 2 == 1)
            {
                t = j * h;
                j = i * h + j * k + t;
                i = i * k + t;
            }
            t = h * h;
            h = 2 * k * h + t;
            k = k * k + t;
            n = n / 2;
        }

        return j;            
    }

    static int FibSum(int n, int m)
    {
        int sum = Program.FibMatrix(n, 1, 1, 0, 0);

        while (n + 1 <= m)
        {
            sum += Program.FibMatrix(n + 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
            n++;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Output : 4
        Console.WriteLine(Program.FibSum(0, 4).ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
f(m+2)-f(n+1)
```

**Example:**

```
for n = 3 to m = 8

Ans1 = f(m+2) = f(10) = 55

Ans2 = f(n+1) = f(4) = 3 

Answer = 55 - 3 = 52
```

Now to calculate the Nth fibonacci in O(logN) 
you can use matrix Exponentiation method

Link:- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/